# google maps infowindow doesn't size correctly to fit image when content is set to jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, google-maps-api-3, backbone-events

I am trying to get my backbone view, that represents an infoWindow, to respond to a click event.

```
App.InfoWindowView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click a": "clickInfoWindow" // fires when any <a> tag in this view is clicked
    }
```

Unfortunately, the only way the click event callback works correctly is by setting the content of the infoWindow to a jQuery object, setting the content to HTML text causes the event to not fire correctly.

```
createInfoWindow: function(){
    this.$el.html(
        window.JST['map-article-infowindow-content'](
        {
            articleData : articleData
        })
     );
     this.infoWindow.setContent(this.$el[0]); // set content to the jQuery object
}
clickInfoWindow: function() // passing an eventObject to this function doesn't fix this
    {
        this.ref = window.open(this.model.get("link"), '_blank', 'location=yes');
        return false;
    }
```

A jQuery object for content works well, except that the infoWindow doesn't size correctly --
[image: incorrectly sized infoWindow]

Setting the content to HTML text directly causes the infoWindow to size correctly, but the backbone events don't fire.

So either I need to:

- Get the backbone events firing on  tags using HTML text

or

- Get the infoWindow sizing correctly with a jQuery object as content

Edit: CSS for infoWindow image:

```
.gm-style-iw img.articleImg{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:auto;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    padding-right:5%;
}
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "size correctly".

Comment: @kinakuta -- See the image in the question -- it overflows from the infoWindow. I am looking for the infoWindow to be large enough to contain all of the elements inside of it.

Comment: What is the markup for the infowindow? As far as events wiring up correctly, my guess is that you just need to set the infowindow view context. The way I've done this is to specify an id for the infowindow in the infowindow view definition. I create an infowindow, then each time it needs to be opened, I create a new infowindow view with the id set to the id for that infowindow.

Comment: can you post your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have some CSS or something that sets the `el`'s width and you need the browser to figure out the height, right?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the infowindow autosizing doesn't respond well to images of variable size.

I have reduced the size of my image, instead of basing it on a percentage of the infoWindow's width.

New image CSS:

```
.gm-style-iw img.articleImg{
    float:left;
    width:125px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    padding-right:5%;
}
```

and this mostly works, as it makes most of the images small enough to fit in the infoWindow.

If anyone knows why infoWindows don't react well with height:auto, or images of variable size, I would be interested to know.